# How is the position of the textarea and input elements with `vertical-align: baseline` calculated?

Tags: css

When placing a vanilla `textarea` and an `input` side by side,

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input />
```

the `textarea` appears higher as shown below,

[image]

Inspecting their CSS in Chrome reveals both have `vertical-align: baseline`. Why aren't they aligned if they have the same alignment value? Where is the baseline against which they're aligned?

Comment: It's complicated. The baseline of form controls, and textarea especially is not well defined. Checkout the example in Firefox. You'll note that the default vertical-align of textarea is not `baseline` but `text-bottom` and if you set it to `baseline`, you get a very different arrangement. It seems that browsers these days put the baseline of input boxes of type=text where the baseline of the value is. There is no consensus over the position of the baseline of textareas.

Comment: @Alohci, thanks, possibly the most useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, there is no `<input></input>` with a closing tag. That does not exist because nothing can go "inside" of that tag.  There is only a self-closing `<input />` tag.

The default values (tested in Firefox) for:

- `<textarea>` is `vertical-align: text-bottom`
- `<input>` is `vertical-align: baseline`

Here's how you can find out
[image: devtools]

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input/>
```

---

EDIT: Now I understand your question. I was confused a bit since apparenly the default styles between Firefox and Chrome are different.  Even setting them both to `baseline` does not fix this.  However setting them both to `bottom` will align them properly in both Firefox and Chrome

```css
textarea, input {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Barr, updated the code snippet

Comment: @aryzing Your question seems to be "where do these styles come from", right?  If so, does this answer your question?

Comment: The question is why are they not aligned if both have (in Chrome) the same alignment ("baseline")

Comment: Well the answer to "why" is that the default styles set them that way. The fix though is to set them to a different value. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox or a grid will help you get consistent positioning.

```css
input, textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.p1, .p2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

.p1 {
  align-items: start;
}

.p2 {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
  <input value="align start">
</p>

<p class="p2">
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
  <input value="align center">
</p>
```